# Find all combination of day and month using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to find out total number of Employee birthdays for **every** day in the year.

I used the following query to get the result:

```
Select S.birthday_month,S.birthday_day,COUNT(id) AS 'No of Birthdays'
            FROM Students S
            GROUP BY S.birthday_month,S.birthday_day
            ORDER BY S.birthday_month,S.birthday_day
```

Result

```
 birthday_month    birthday_day      No of Birthdays
    April            16                 2
    May               1                  1
    June              5                  1
    September         22                 1
```

What i would actually want is all possible combination of month and day and put value of 0 in **No of Birthdays** if it doesn't exist.

Here is my desired output

```
   birthday_month    birthday_day      No of Birthdays
    Jan                  1                0
    Jan                  2                0
    Jan                  3                0
                  etc
                  etc
    April              16                 2
    May                1                  1
    June               5                  1
    September          22                 1
                  etc
                  etc
    Dec                30                 0
    Dec                31                 0
```

Comment: Create a table with all possible combinations on birthday_month and birthday_day (366 entries to account for a leap year) and left join it with the dataset that you already got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is a `left join` . . . but you need a list of days.  One method is to generate the dates and strip out the year:

```
with dates as (
      select cast('2000-01-01' as date) as dte, datename(month, '2000-01-01') as mon, 1 as day, 1 as lev
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte), datename(month, dateadd(day, 1, dte)), day(dateadd(day, 1, dte)) lev + 1
      from dates
      where dte < '2000-12-31'
     )
select d.mon, d.day, count(s.birthday_month)
from dates d left join
     students s
     on s.birthday_month = d.mon and s.birthday_day = d.day
group by d.mon, d.day
order by d.lev
option (maxrecursion 0);
```